# File Writer and File Reader error

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter

I have this code to read from a text file and then modify it. Then write the modified content to another text file.
I am getting a null pointer exception at `out.write(read);` And also, not all lines are being written, can some one help me please. Thank you

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class File
{
    BufferedReader in;
    BufferedWriter out;
    String read;

    public File()
    {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.txt"));
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));

            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                read = in.readLine();
                //Write codes to modify file here
                //___codes not written yet______//
                out.write(read);
                scan.next();
                System.out.println("file output: " + read);                 
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was a problem:" + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File File = new File();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
while((read = in.readLine()) != null)
```

instead of

```
while (scan.hasNext())
```

Comment: what is problem with that?

Comment: @VishalRathod Maybe it isn't clever to read twice if you like to process _every_ line?

Comment: Thank you, I can now see what caused the problem :)

Comment: @VishalRathod Because the code calls `in.readLine()` twice? You see OPs code, so you also see what he does in the loop body.

Comment: @VishalRathod Tom doesn't mean read the *same* line twice. He means reading two lines after each other, causing the program to skip the first line read.

Answer (score 0):

need to change :`while((read = in.readLine()) != null).`